# How long can one safely take paracetamol for?

Tags: liver, toxicity

I've heard that paracetamol is pretty bad for the liver - in fact, it relies so much on the human liver breaking it down that one pill of the stuff will kill a cat, whose liver can't deal with it!

With that in mind, and assuming no alcohol intake during the same period, how long can the average healthy adult continue to take paracetamol for if they take it at the generally recommended dose - 1000mg four times a day?  How long until there is a risk of serious liver damage?

Comment: "Primarily opinion-based"?  Oh, come on.  Surely there are some facts on paracetamol toxicity.  I'm starting to think someone has a vendetta to close my questions.

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based, but I do think it's pretty broad and generic. I don't think you'll get much better of an answer than comes on the safety/interaction sheet that comes with it. It's basically a question that can be found with a google search, which while not off topic, is frowned upon on most SE sites that I frequent.

Comment: The instructions generally tell you how much to take daily, but not for how long.

Comment: Yeah, because different people react differently. They aren't going to open themselves up to a lawsuit by saying "Sure, take it for a week, no problem", and then get sued when someone reacts after 4 days. Plus, they have no information on other drugs the person is or may take in the future, etc. Your "typical healthy adult" is a myth. :) :)

Comment: @Jez I've gotten a fair dose of "Primarily opinion-based" close votes on my questions as well... I don't get it either.

Comment: @JohnP Maybe a myth but still a good point of reference.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Maybe the opinion based votes are because the questions are asking for broad, sweeping generalities? I haven't looked at all your questions, so that is just a theory. (Also, IIRC, you tend to ask a lot of one line "why" questions, which also lends itself to that type of close vote). Not a criticism, just an observation.

Comment: @JohnP Good point, I see what you mean, I haven't thought that too opinion-based could be used that way. Probably much more explicit to vote as too broad though, but I can see the intent.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I've often thought that too broad and opinion based have a lot of overlap between them. :/

Comment: A point about that cat:  One pill would be in the danger zone for a cat-sized human, also.